# ContainerView hide UILabel

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uilabel

I want to use UILabel in ContainerView.
So I am using this code for that.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 60, 300, 150)] autorelease];
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
myLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.5];
myLabel.text = [theQuiz objectAtIndex:row+3] ;
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
[myLabel sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];

//ContainerView
UIView *ChallengeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 55, 300, 10 + Challenge.frame.size.height)];
ChallengeView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor purpleColor ] CGColor];
[ChallengeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
ChallengeView.layer.cornerRadius = 8 ;
ChallengeView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
[self.view addSubview:ChallengeView];
[ChallengeView release];
```

Now problem is that when i set background color for ContainerView it hides the text of **myLabel**

Any Solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you containerView is being added above label either you add label after containerView or do this:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the ChallengeView first , Then add the myLabel.
Otherwise u can do as like @xs2bush said,

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myLabel];
```

Bcz the ChallengeView hides the label.

Comment: I got it.. :) Thanx EXC_ .. !!